# SML: Inputting an empty list into function gives error "Warning: type vars not generalized because of value restriction..."

Tags: types, compiler-errors, ml

My function is meant to place the first item in the list at the end of the list.
The list may be of any type.
I tried to anticipate an empty list input but I get error regarding types.

What can I do to have this code work as intended?

```
fun cycle1 aList = if null(aList) then []else tl(aList) @ [hd aList];
cycle1 [];

stdIn:24.1-24.10 Warning: type vars not generalized because of
   value restriction are instantiated to dummy types (X1,X2,...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an error, just a warning.

```
- fun cycle1 aList = if null(aList) then []else tl(aList) @ [hd aList];
val cycle1 = fn : 'a list -> 'a list
- cycle1 [];
stdIn:2.1-2.10 Warning: type vars not generalized because of
   value restriction are instantiated to dummy types (X1,X2,...)
val it = [] : ?.X1 list
```

Note that there actually is a result - `[]` - which is a list of a "dummy type", `?.X1 list`.

This happens because a value can't be polymorphic (you can't create an `'a list`).
Search for the *value restriction* for details.

You can avoid the warning by using the empty list of a specific type:

```
- cycle1 ([] :int list);
val it = [] : int list
- cycle1 ([] : string list);
val it = [] : string list
```

On a side note, I would recommend that you get familiar with pattern matching as soon as possible, as it makes code much more readable;

```
fun cycle1 [] = []
  | cycle1 (x::xs) = xs @ [x]
```